# SOLR returns docs for empty query but not for a real query

Tags: solr

I have a basic SOLR instance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="my-solr" version="1.5">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" indexed="true" />
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" indexed="true"/>
  </types>

  <fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
  </fields>

  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

If I issue an empty query from the SOLR admin page, I get some results:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">1</int>
    <lst name="params">
    <str name="indent">on</str>
    <str name="start">0</str>
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="version">2.2</str>
    <str name="rows">10</str>
    </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="5" start="0">
        <doc><str name="id">1</str><arr name="title"><str>Test</str></arr></doc>
        <doc><str name="id">2</str><arr name="title"><str>Other Test</str></arr></doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

But if I issue the query `title:"test"` (correct me if I have the wrong syntax), I get nothing.

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">0</int>
    <lst name="params">
    <str name="indent">on</str>
    <str name="start">0</str>
    <str name="q">title:"test"</str>
    <str name="version">2.2</str>
    <str name="rows">10</str>
    </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't indexing in a way I expected because I wasn't using an appropriate analyzer. I took the example `text_general` type as shipped in the example `schema.xml`, and that works pretty much. This is enough to get going. Reproduced here.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your schema the title field is set to indexed="true". Only indexed fields can be specified in query (and only fields that have stored="true" can be requested to be returned).

If you change the schema, i would recommend to restart solr and re-index everything.

From what i saw in your output to empty query it also seems that you defined title as multivalued/array. This does not make sense in most cases. Example for title field:

`<field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>`

Note that you should only "store" fields that you need returned later on.

Comment: Every field is indexed as far as I'm aware. Did I make a mistake in my schema? I delete the data and re-start every change. I'll try with single value, but I will want to use multi-values at some point with other fields.

Comment: Hard to say if you don't post your field configs in schema. But of course if you used the wrong type / factory it will not find anything.

Comment: Multi-Value or not is a configuration per field. To keep structure clean i would recommend to only use it for fields that are actually arrays. If a doc has two titles, something probably went wrong and you want to get an error message. Multiple categories however are quite possible. 

For indexing you anyway have two possibilities:

1) Put everything into one field with copytext and use the standard parser

2) Put everything into mulitple fields with copytext (and e.g. different strategies) and use edismax parser with priorities...

Comment: I posted the entire schema (with some bits removed for simplicity). I found out what the problem is, thanks for your help.